# Issue with hibernate ehcache configuration: Error configuring from null. Initial cause was null

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am trying to implement 2nd level cache in our product with hibernate version 3.

However when I try to access my application, I get following error:

> [ HibernateSessionFactory ] :
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:102)
>   [wrapped] net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from null.
>   Initial cause was null
>
> at
>   net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:105)
>
> at
>   net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.HibernateUtil.loadAndCorrectConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:51)
>
> at
>   net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.start(SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.java:76)
>
> [wrapped] org.hibernate.cache.CacheException:
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from null. Initial
>   cause was null
>
> at
>   net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.start(SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.java:82)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:238)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
...
...

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache>

<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="500" timeToLiveSeconds="1000" />

    <cache name="Audit" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="500" timeToLiveSeconds="1000" />  
</ehcache>
```

I am using following jars to implement cache:

- ehcache-core-2.6.10.jar
- hibernate-3.6.6.jar
- hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar

Please guide me, where it is going wrong. Why it shows file as null. Both configuration files are in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by replacing the following line :

```
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</property>
```

with

```
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">META-INF/config/ehcache.xml</property>
```

Although both files were in same folder but it was not recognizing the file. so, META-INF did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the `ehcache,xml` file that isn't found. Can you try with `/ehcache.xml`?

Comment: I tried that option too, but it did not work. However after 3 days of time waste I found the solution. Please check my answer for same.

Comment: yes... if your file is in config/ then specifying it seems the way to go... You should have told us where the file was in your question. It looked like it was at the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of continuous tries I found the issue. As per post on internet, I found that it reads configuration from classpath only.

Though my both configuration files were at same location, they were at **classpath:config/** location. So changing my configuration as per following worked for me:

```
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">config/ehcache.xml</property>
```